# Change Button Border Properties on IBAction

Tags: xcode, cocoa, ibaction, nsbutton

Why does this allow me to change the **bordered state** but not the **border width** (or other border properties)?

```
NSButton *button = (NSButton *)sender;
[button setBordered:false];
[button setBorderWidth:5];
```

Comment: The buttons do not have a borderWidth Property! Stupid.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `setBorderWidth:` method does not exists, check the [NSButton Class Reference](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Reference/ApplicationKit/Classes/nsbutton_Class/Reference/Reference.html).
In other words, `NSButton` does not support changing the border width (by default).
The `setBordered:` method defines wether the button has a bezeled border.
Setting `setBordered:` to `false` removes the complete bezel, for example:

[image: With Bezel] [image: Without Bezel]

The `setBordered:` method might be confusing therefor.